# How to tell python to use a specific value from a lst by inputing an integer of a postion (of the lst)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and i spent over an hour looking for this with no luck.

So i have a def function which takes as an input a lst and a position.

I need python to correspond the inputed position to the lst and use whatever value is reflected on that position of the lst to calculate further.

```
    def somefunction(lst, position):
        for i, value in enumerate(lst):
            if value < int(position):    #this just uses the inputed value position and not the actual position value from the list
                count += 1
        return count

    >>> somefunction([21, 4, 5, 66, 4, 3, 555], 2)
    2
```

so at position 2 we have 5 and i need my code to return a count of all numbers smaller than 5 *to the right of it only*. so the answer would be 2...... since 4 and 3 are smaller than 5.

Comment: I don't understand, so you want to pass in an index, then find the number of elements smaller than the element with that index in the list?

Comment: yes, index will be used as a position from the list...whichever value is at that position....then find the number of element smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def somefunction(lst, position):
   count=0
   for i in range(position,len(lst)):
       if lst[i] < lst[position]:    
          count += 1
   return count


somefunction([21, 4, 5, 66, 4, 3,555], 2)
```

There are lots of ways to do it. as said by above people. since you have asked something similar to your code , i hope this helps you out. but as a beginner you could explore all options also

Answer (score 3):

```
def somefunction(my_list, index):
    value, tail = my_list[index], my_list[index + 1:]
    return sum(1 for element in tail if element < value)
```

Comment: this doesn't work because when we use somefucntion ([1, 4, 2, 9, 4], 2) the answer should be 2 but its showing 0

Comment: @Michelle: how are 9 and 4 less than 2?

Comment: @Michelle Now I'm REALLY confused.

Comment: so sorry i was looking at the wrong thing. this works great just trying to understand it now.

Comment: could some variation of my code be used to get the same result?

Comment: @Michelle look at your if statement - you need to modify your code to compare some _values_ to one _value_, at the moment you compare some _values_ to an _index_ which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The "tail" of a list after the position `n` is `lst[n+1:]` in python:

```
>>> lst = [21, 4, 5, 66, 4, 3, 555]
>>> n = 2
>>> tail = lst[n+1:]
>>> tail
[66, 4, 3, 555]
```

To pick all elements that meet a certain condition you use a "list comprehension":

```
>>> smaller = [x for x in tail if x < lst[n]]
>>> smaller
[4, 3]
```

Finally, to count items in a list, use `len`:

```
>>> count = len(smaller)
>>> count
2
```

Hope this helps.